# Easyuml plugin for Netbeans returning error when editing package name for a class

Tags: java, netbeans-8

When I try to edit a package name of a class in the class diagram on Easyuml plugin for netbeans 8.0.2, it returns me an error message saying : "Component [name of the class] already exists in package [name of the package]" in any name I try. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show us the contents of the diagram?

Comment: It happens even when I create a Class diagram from Scratch. When I try to edit the name of the class´ package that I´ve just created, this message dialog shows up